# given N red candy and M blue candy. find the number of arrangements in which not more than K candy of the same color are placed next to each other?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

what i understand is we need to find all the permutations of N+M.
I stuck after this can anyone help which data structure to use here.

First i create a string of N+M and ther call it to

````
static String[] getper(String str) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (str.length() == 0) {
            String arr[] = { "" };
            return arr;
        }
        char c = str.charAt(0);
        String restOfString = str.substring(1);
        String[] rr = getper(restOfString);

        int k = 0;
        String result[];

        // create array, not the base case
        if (rr.length == 1 && rr[0] == "") {
            result = new String[1];
        } else {
            result = new String[(rr[0].length() + 1) * rr.length];
        }
        
        for (int i = 0; i < rr.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("for value:" + rr[i] + " inserting:" + c);
            for (int j = 0; j <= rr[i].length(); j++) {
                result[k] = rr[i].substring(0, j) + c + rr[i].substring(j);
                k++;
            }

        }
        return result;
    }```
````

Comment: What are the maximum values of N, M and K?

Comment: you can take 10^2 for for all three

Answer (score 1):

It's not real to generate enormous quantity of all combinations for large values of `M` and `N`.

But we can calculate number of variants without `K+1` similar candies in row.

Make tables of size `(N+M+1)x(N+1)x(K+1)` and `(N+M+1)x(M+1)x(K+1)` for red and for blue candies.

Entry `Red[i][r][j]` contains number of good sequences of length `i` ending with `j` red candies using `r` red candies at all (we need to limit overall number of red candies by `N`)

Similar for `Blue[i][b][j]`

We can calculate how many good sequences do exist for `Red[i][r][j]`, adding one red candy to any cell of `Blue[i-1][i-1-b-1]` row. Also we can add one red candies to cells `Red[i-1][r-1][j<K]` (all except those ending with `K` reds).

Fill red and blue tables layer-by-layer, and sum of the last layers (`Red[N+M] and Blue[N+M]`) is needed number of variants.